# How to add an icon to the Tab control in FXML?

Tags: user-interface, tabs, controls, javafx, fxml

I'm using javafx 2.0. I want to add an icon to the Tab in fxml:

example:

```
     <TabPane>
         <tabs>
            <Tab text="abc" >
            </Tab> 
         </tabs>
     </TabPane>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
<Tab> 
    <graphic>
        <ImageView>
            <image>
                    <Image url="@image.png"/>
            </image>
        </ImageView>
    </graphic>
    <content>
        ...
    </content>
</Tab>
```

Comment: @SomethingSomething take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20591264/4135367